# How do you get just the image URL in Orchard CMS?

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have made a "Team" content type and have a list page and a profile page. I have 3 custom fields for Position, Bio and Profile Image. The single profile page is all working as I'd like.

What I'm wanting to get on the listing page is the profile image as a background on a div but can't for the life of me work out how its done. I can get the image to show as an  element. Done this by adding:

```
<Match ContentType="Team">
    <Match DisplayType="Summary">
        <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker="Content:1"/>
    </Match>
</Match>
```

But struggling to work out how to just get the URL to the profile image so that I can put it as in inline style on the div as a background.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Anto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the override View you can get the image like this:

```
var url = Model.ContentItem.TeamPart.ProfileImage.MediaParts[0].MediaUrl;
```

Notice that the `TeamPart` is the part that is created by attaching fields to your team content item. The `ProfileImage` is the name of your MediaLibraryPickerField field.

**EDIT**

Since at least Orchard 1.9 (not sure since when) you can do:

```
var url = Model.ContentItem.TeamPart.ProfileImage.FirstMediaUrl;
```

Comment: Hi Devqon, many thanks for your help. I have put the above in and receive this error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

I can follow the above down the shape tracer and MediaParts has List<MediaPart> on the right. Surly the 0 index would exist here?

Comment: Ignore that, one of the 2 team profiles did not have an image uploaded doh! Uploaded one and its working perfect. Thanks for your help once again

Comment: Yeah offcourse you should check for null reference for when there is no image uploaded :) glad I could help

Comment: Yeh, dropped in a check to make sure media parts actually had items, if not return an empty string :)

Comment: You'll probably want to implement in that case a default 'No Image' image